# How can I check if something is a Raphael object?

Tags: javascript, raphael

Given a JavaScript object, how can I check if it is a Raphael object (not the paper, but a circle, path, etc.)?

`Raphael.el` represents the generic element prototype; I think I want to test

```
x.__proto__ === Raphael.el
```

in a cross browser way, but I am not completely sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate a little and add some more relevant info (it took me a little while to figure out the accepted answer, and I'm clearly not alone looking at the other answers, also, the accepted answer only works for *one type* of Raphael object: it solves the original question, this is a more complete resource).

---

### Detecting Raphael elements

Using `x.constructor.prototype == Raphael.el`, you're taking `x`, the variable that might be a Raphael ***element*** (circle, path etc - **not** a Raphael `set` or `paper` object) and comparing the prototype of the function that constructed it with the prototype for Raphael elements in Raphael itself (Raphael is a function object, el is a defined property of it).

This works, but it also won't find raphael objects based on different prototypes to Raphael.el, like sets and paper objects:

---

### Detecting Raphael sets

If you wanted to test if something was a Raphael set, the set prototype is in `Raphael.st` so you could test if a variable is a Raphael set using:

`someSet.constructor.prototype ==  Raphael.st`

---

### Detecting Raphael paper objects

As for the equivalent for sniffing Raphael **paper** objects, since they are created using `Raphael()` function, you can use:

`paper.constructor.prototype ==  Raphael.prototype`

---

The above three are basically the same as...

`someSet.constructor.prototype ==  paper.circle().constructor.prototype`

...or...

`someSet.constructor.prototype ==  paper.set().constructor.prototype`

...or...

`someSet.constructor.prototype ==  Raphael().constructor.prototype`

...but without *actually running those functions*, so avoiding wasted processing (and avoiding Raphael() complaining that it hasn't been passed an ID).

---

### Detecting sub-types of object (e.g. rectangle, circle...)

None of the above works for subtypes of Raphael elements - e.g. if you compare a circle with `R.rect().constructor.prototype`, it returns **`true`**.

This is because both circles and rectangles are made using the *element* prototype defined in `Raphael.el`. For these, however, Raphael makes it easy:

`someRectangle.type == "rect"`

`someCircle.type == "circle"`

...etc..

Comment: Don't know if it is new but elements like sets now have a type property. You can do yourSet.type == "set".

Comment: Should we rather use === instead of ==?

Answer (score 4):

Pablo posted an answer that was not quite correct but gave me inspiration towards finding a correct solution:

```
x.constructor.prototype == Raphael.el
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use the `constructor` property and check against the function that created the object (I'm assuming it's called `Raphael` but I haven't used the lib).

**Edit**

Checked the lib site, you actually do it that way:

`obj.constructor === Raphael //true`

Comment: Unfortunately this actually doesn't work. It checks whether `obj` is a reference to the drawing canvas instead of whether it is something *on* the canvas, which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I wasnt able to use the mentioned answer. But what worked for me was to compare explicitly with string `"Raphaël’s object"`.

Eg:

```
var textName = paper.getElementByPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY);
if (textName== "Raphaël’s object")
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Nice little uitlity function, `paper.getElementByPoint`. Thanks!