# RaphaelJS Set.forEach()

Tags: javascript, raphael

I read in the documentation raphaeljs description of [Set.forEach](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Set.forEach), and can't understand
how it works. Please can anyone give me an example of usage.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here you have a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9X6rM/

And this is the important part of It:

```
set.forEach(function(e){
    e.attr({fill:'#000'})
})
```

Its a little bit tricky at first, but its pretty handy when you get it. You need to pass to the `forEach()` method the function that you want to execute on each element, and this function need to have, like an argument, a variable name to bind to the element. So in this case `e` is the rectangle that is being processed. Got it?

Comment: Thank you limoragni & Grooveek, you really help me

Comment: You are welcome. And its the same with the paper.forEach. For further information, this site 
could be helpful: http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?v=2#pagetop

Comment: The old "Time is money" turned into "time is love". I've loved many of the kind answers on this site too, so, we're even!

Answer (score 3):

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/raphaeljs/msg/3bb0675db61a8f0b) is pretty helpful in understanding how `forEach` works

Edit :

You have a working example in the [Raphaël Documentation](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Raphael.st)

```
Raphael.el.red = function () {
    this.attr({fill: "#f00"});
};
Raphael.st.red = function () {
    this.forEach(function (el) {
        el.red();
    });
};
// then use it
paper.set(paper.circle(100, 100, 20), paper.circle(110, 100, 20)).red();
```

Comment: can you please give me an example of usage

Answer (score 2):

Some things that are missing from the Raphael `forEach` documentation:

### **What is passed to the function you define**

```
set.forEach(function(element, index){
    element.attr({fill:'#000'});
    alert('This is the element that can be accessed as set['+index+']');
})
```

Two arguments are passed passed to the callback function:

1. The Raphael element that is currently being looked at.
2. The index number indicating the position of that Raphael element in the set.

`this` in the scope of a cycle of Raphael's `forEach` is unchanged from the surrounding function (unlike jQuery's `.each()`).

### **Possible crashes or unexpected behaviour**

- Unlike jQuery's `.each()` function, Raphael's `.forEach()` crashes out if it's passed a singular Raphael element instead of a set. If a variable might contain one element, or might contain a set of multiple elements, [check what type of Raphael object it is first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6475689/568458).
- As mentioned, Raphael's `.forEach()` doesn't create a closure like in jQuery - it's really just an iteration through an array. Variables in each iteration aren't 'frozen' in that iteration, they can be overwritten by following iterations.