# what is the equivalent of $(domnode) in Raphael js

Tags: raphael

When we do `$(domnode)` we get all jquery methods attached to domnode.
Similarly what is the equivalent for that in Raphael js

`WhatRaphaelmethod(svgRectnode)` gives a Raphael element object?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such selectior mechanism in raphael. But you can use jQuery with svg nodes as well as with html nodes. So for example if you have created the svg canvas and put path on it. You can use jQuery to get this node $('path') and get access to all atributes of that node. But in this case you cant treat thit object as an raphael object of cause.

And I agree with limoragni...you can make a set of set where you will put all of you raphael objects in order to make them grouped. Some thing  like that:

{pathes : [a set of raphael pathes], circles: [a set of circles], etc}

or any other order that you need in your algoritm

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use `getById('elementID')`. This is an internal ID that works separate from the nodes. So you need to set this ID yourself. I've answered a question before on this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461716/adding-ids-to-raphael-objects/8536743#8536743)

You also can group elements in sets, and then use `set.ForEach()` or you can use `paper.forEach()` to select all the elements. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034714/raphaeljs-set-foreach/9039287#9039287) I answered another question that could help.

Comment: sorry...that requires setting id, and may not be helpful if i get a raw svg node.

Comment: You need to convert the raw svg into a raphael's one. Otherwise you are not going to be able to use the raphaels's methods that are only possible to use on raphel's objects. So, at the moment in wich you convert the svg you must set the Id, thats the way of using this framework, if you use the raw svg forget about IE compatibility. Again, this pos (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461716/adding-ids-to-raphael-objects/8536743#8536743)t could be helpful for you in order to turn the raw svg into a raphael object, and add the Id's. Bye!